# How is `outline: inherit 0` interpreted?

Tags: css, web-standards, css-parsing

[According to w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_outline.asp), the syntax of `outline` is:
`outline: <color> <style> <width>;` and either of the three can be missing.

And the value `inherit` is a valid value of either three, or a single `outline: inherit` means that it should inherit all three.

I'm asking this because I'm working on property optimizer for a CSS minifier. According to the above link,
`outline: inherit none 3px` is equivalent to `outline: inherit 3px`, and
`outline: invert inherit 3px` is also equivalent to `outline: inherit 3px`,
but the result seems too ambigous.

So the question is, how do browsers interpret `outline: inherit 0px`? Do they assign `inherit` to the color or the style?

Comment: Please don’t link “according to W3C” with w3schools.com _ever_ – because: http://www.w3fools.com/. And as for the question itself: What is the result of your own testing in different browsers?

Comment: @CBroe I fully agree with you, specially because as you can see people start mixing up the World Wide Web Consortium (W3C) and this third party site.

Comment: Never mind the confusion between W3C and W3Schools - where does W3Schools even say that "the value `inherit` is a valid value of either three"?

Comment: Sorry, I was under the impression that w3schools is somehow related to the W3C.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is ignored. This is current browser practice and the intended principle in CSS: for a shorthand notation like `outline`, the keyword `inherit` is allowed as a value (making all the sub-properties inherited), but not in conjunction with any other value. The reason is rather obvious: otherwise the value would not have an unambiguous interpretation. In the value `inherit 0`, the value `0` can only be a value for `outline-width`, but `inherit` could be a value for `outline-style` or `outline-color`.

The principle is mentioned in an appendix of the CSS 2.1 specification, at [C.3.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/changes.html#q142). In theory, appendix C is an informative description of changes, not normative, and here it does not reflect an actual change. That is, this was goofed up: the intent was described, but normatively CSS 2.1 does not have this principle and would regard `outline: inherit 0` as valid (but the W3C CSS Validator rejects it). Cf. to [Is this font: shorthand property syntax valid? (My reading of the spec says yes, but half of my installed browsers disagree.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5518500/is-this-font-shorthand-property-syntax-valid-my-reading-of-the-spec-says-yes) (which deals with the same issue regarding the `font` shorthand).

If you want all `outline` properties to be inherited but width set to zero (which would be somewhat odd), you need two declarations

```
outline: inherit;
outline-width: 0;
```

Comment: Thank you Jukka for your answer, I wasn't aware that `inherit` couldn't be used inside shorthand declarations.

Answer (score 0):

It should be noted that w3schools definition for *order* is not complete. All of the following are valid

```
outline: <color> <style> <width>
outline: <color> <width> <style> 


outline: <width> <style> <color>
outline: <width> <color> <style>


outline: <style> <width> <color>
outline: <style> <color> <width>
```

Because the ordering doesn't matter. This in turn becomes the reason for `outline: inherit none 3px` to become invalid, as `3px` could signify `color` as well.

Similarily `outline: inherit 0px` is equivalent to `outline: inherit initial 0px` and thus could refer to `outline-color: 0px`.