# Why does outline-color: inherit/inherit not work in the shorthand property outline: inherit dotted 2px?

Tags: html, css

Consider the following demo:

```css
a {
  outline: initial dotted 2px;
}

.two {
  
  outline-style: dotted;
  outline-width: 2px;
  outline-color: initial;
}
```

```html
<a href="#!">hello</a>

<br>
<br>

 <a href="#!" class="two">hello2</a>
```

The first anchor tag doesn't get any outline. The dev tools say it's an invalid property value. The same goes for `inherit`. Why is that?

Comment: initial will go (cover) for every values in that case of a shorthand syntax . try with two values `outline: initial unset red` ... initial and unset are supposed to match which style, size or border ?

Comment: @G-Cyrillus According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/outline#formal_syntax) initial should match `outlne-color` and `unset` should match `outline-style`

Comment: not really https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial I understand this what we would expect, but in reality it works otherwise unfortunately. maybe a use case not implemented or clear enough.

Comment: It can be applied to any css property but your order in `outline: initial unset red` is invalid. First property has to be outline color and last has to be `outline-width`. `red` is not correct for `outline-width`

Comment: I think I am misinterpreting the MDN order `||`.

Comment: I agree we would expect it to work that way, but obviously it does not :(

Comment: @G-Cyrillus Can outline have both  orders: `outline: <color> <style> <width>` and `outline: <width>  <style> <color>`. My question is somehow answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21810859/3429430 but I am not sure if that makes my question duplicate.

Comment: looks like a good duplicate to me ;)  inherit,unset,initial,revert have a similar way to be applied, i believe.

Comment: if you follow the official syntax: https://drafts.csswg.org/css-ui-3/#outline you will find that initial cannot be a value there. initial can only be a value **alone** applied to the property. It's a special value that apply to the whole property and can never be a part of its value

Comment: here is the syntax of color value: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-color-4/#typedef-color .. again, you will never find initial there because initial is not a `<color>` value. it's a value that can apply to the `color` property (note the difference between `<color>` as value and `color` as property)